# Is denormalized table an acceptable option in this case?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, database-schema

I would like your opinion on which table structure to go with.

Let's say it's a table to store nba players info.
So you would have the `id, name, team_id` etc.

But to store the players playing position (Point Guard, Power Forward, Center etc) should I create a separate `Player_Position` table that connects `Player_ID` to `Position`?

**Player** Table:

```
ID      Name       Team_ID
-------------------------
1    LeBron James    10
2    CJ McCollum     5
```

**Player_Position** Table:

```
Player_ID  Position
-------------------
  1          PG
  1          SF
  1          PF
  2          PG
  2          SG
```

The other option is to have columns `PG, SG, SF, PF, C` as columns on the `Players` table so if a player plays `PG` and `SG`, those fields would be 1 and others 0.

**Player** Table:

```
ID     Name          Team_ID   PG  SG  SF  PF  C
-------------------------------------------------
1   LeBron James      10       1   0   1   1   0
2   CJ McCollum       5        1   1   0   0   0
```

`Player` has at least 1 position, can be multiple, (can be all 5).
No new positions will be invented later, none will be removed, just those 5.

Comment: Your first `Player_Position` table is normalized and is preferable to the second one having separate columns for each position.  To the first table you might also need to add time information, e.g. which season the relationship represents.

Comment: Thank you, I should add that I might manually edit those positions, so I would much prefer the second option to do that. So my question becomes what kind of clear advantages does a normalized table have that the other option doesn't?

Comment: I'm not sure that editing is easier in either case.  Also the second option has a big flaw which is that if you need new positions then you have to take the rather draconian action of adding new columns.

Comment: Yeah, I agree in general. However in this particular case, as I've mentioned in my original question "No new positions will be invented later, none will be removed, just those 5."

I guess I'm just trying to justify using a "bad" schema because it would be easier for me to manually edit. (and yes it would be easier to edit in the second option). But you're right, first option is the proper way to do it. Thanks Tim

Comment: The second table can be useful for performance, but is the least flexible to change and general queries. If you're *already* experiencing performance issues, then perhaps consider this denormalisation option, perhaps as a derived table, but not before. In general this would be premature optimisation, your gains would probably be very marginal, you would lock yourself into future difficulties, and they could introduce Real performance costs. Don't do it, stay normalised for as long as you can, and if you need to go denormalised, keep Both, one derived from the other... Imho

Comment: Which [normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) does your second player table violate?

Answer (score 0):

Consider this single column:

```
positions SET('PG', 'SG', 'SF', 'PF', 'C') NOT NULL
```

Think about the queries to set/change/fetch the data.  Then read the docs to see the contorted way you have to use `SET`.